# Помогите пожалуйста проверять эту предложению. У меня нет русско-испанский словарь

Tags: морфология

Помогите пожалуйста проверять эту предложению. У меня нет русско-испанский словарь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогите, пожалуйста, провер**и**ть эт**о** предложени**е**.

У меня нет русско-испанск**ого** словар**я**.

Comment: Болшое Спасибо.

Comment: Правильно писать так: _Большое спасибо._